# grouping by year works with 'unixepoch' but not with 'localtime'

Tags: sqlite, datetime, group-by, max, min

```
CREATE TABLE FiveMinutesData (
    TimeStamp datetime NOT NULL,
    V_Ph1 float, V_Ph2 float, V_Ph3 float,
    P_Ph1 float, P_Ph2 float, P_Ph3 float,
    P_Ph1_Day float, P_Ph2_Day float, P_Ph3_Day float,
    Flags int,
    PRIMARY KEY (TimeStamp)
);

sqlite>   select min(timestamp), max(timestamp)  FROM fiveminutesdata group by strftime('%Y',datetime(TimeStamp,'localtime')); 

1290948000|1647001800

sqlite>   select min(timestamp), max(timestamp)  FROM fiveminutesdata group by strftime('%Y',datetime(TimeStamp,'unixepoch')); 

1290948000|1293812700
1293873900|1325347800
1325410500|1356970500
1357032600|1388507700
1388565900|1420070100
1420070700|1451606100
1451606400|1483228500
1483228800|1514764500
1514764800|1546300500
1546300800|1577836500
1577836800|1609458900
1609459200|1640994600
1640997300|1647001800
```

It looks that the yearly grouping with , when using localtime, is grouping everything in on line.
Is there an explanation for this behavior?
A work around ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column `timestamp` contains integer values which are unix epoch values, so you have to use the modifier `'unixepoch'` and `'localtime'`:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y', datetime(timestamp, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) year,
       MIN(timestamp) min_timestamp, 
       MAX(timestamp) max_timestamp
FROM fiveminutesdata 
GROUP BY year;
```

Or, simpler:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y', timestamp, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') year,
       MIN(timestamp) min_timestamp, 
       MAX(timestamp) max_timestamp
FROM fiveminutesdata 
GROUP BY year;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This did it. One small remark, after "year" in the select, should be placed a comma.

Comment: @pasquinel of course. I edited.